# Best way of determining what the maximum possible width of a collection view cell is based the size of a label?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I'm running into the following issue:

- I have a horizontal scrolling collection view.
- I require all my collection view cells to be the exact same width. This is a requirement from a designer.
- My collection view cells simply have a label in a subview that must be centered horizontally and vertically (and at least 20px from the top/bottom and sides). The label is 1 line always.

In order to determine the maximum width is, I thought I would setup a cell offscreen and cycle through each of my strings. I would call `prepareForReuse` on the cell to set it back up for the next string. For example:

```
for viewmodel in vms {
  cell.setupCell(cellViewModel: viewmodel)
  cell.layoutIfNeeded()
  print("Size = \(cell.frame.size.width)")
  cell.prepareForReuse()
}
```

The `Size =` always prints 144 (which is the width of the cell in the .xib). 
Once the app is running though, the cells have all different widths.

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

  func setupCell(cellViewModel: CellViewModel) {
    titleLabel.text = cellViewModel.title
  }

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.titleLabel.text = ""
    self.backgroundImageView.image = nil
  }
}
```

How do I calculate this width properly before hand, so I can set them all size widths to the largest width (to ensure all my content is showing properly).

If it makes a difference, my collectionView here inside a tableview and my `CollectionViewCell` has an inequality width constraint of >144 (it currently grows to show all content).

Comment: Can you provide code for how you are setting up your label?

Comment: `titleLabel.text = cellViewModel.title` is all I have now (was an attributed string before).